# Как создается экземпляр класса за кулисами?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Кое-где видел что при вызове класса, вызывается метод `__call__`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут решается вопрос с тем, как попадают в метод `__init__` аргументы, когда мы переопределяем метод `__new__`.
Но это не логично потому что мы передаём в качестве параметров **self** когда экземпляр ещё не создан. Да и при перопределении данного метода в **pass**, все будет нормально работать.
Ещё где-то читал что данный метод никак не влияет на создание экземляра.
Так как же создается экземпляр на самом деле?
Про метод `__new__` можете не говорить, я знаю, но не понимаю, как аргументы передаются в метод `__init__` если мы их не передаем в родительский метод `__new__` и вообще больше нигде не передаём?!
И да, я знаю что метод `__call__` нужен чтобы сделать экземпляр вызываемым, то есть **callable**

Comment: В методе new нет self.

Comment: Это может говорить о том, что вызов метода ___init___ происходит не из ___new___, а на уровне интерпретатора после вызова __new__.

Answer (score 6):

Рассмотрим простой тестовый пример, чтобы разобраться с порядком вызова функций:

```py
class Test:
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'__call__ called with value {self.value}')

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('__new__ called')
        return object.__new__(Test)

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = '999'
        print('__init__ called')

t = Test()
print('some string printed')
t()
```

Вывод:

```bash
__new__ called
__init__ called
some string printed
__call__ called with value 999
```

При создании экземпляра класса, первым делом вызывается функция `__new__`. Ее задача - вернуть пустой объект, для которого мы и создадим все нужные поля.

После этого вызывается функция `__init__` (Этот момент я попрошу запомнить, почему так происходит я расскажу чуть позже). Ее задача - задать все необходимые поля для объекта, который нам вернула функция `__new__`.

Теперь объект создан и мы можем с ним работать. Печатаем какую-нибудь строку.

И теперь при вызове `t()`. Будет вызвана функция `__call__`. Она НЕ участвует в создании объекта и вызывается при попытке обратиться к **уже созданному объекту**, как к функции (со скобочками). (О том, где вы могли слышать про **call** в создании объекта я тоже расскажу чуть ниже)

Теперь предлагаю посмотреть на выжимку из исходного кода CPython (находится [здесь](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/typeobject.c#L1224)):

```
static PyObject *
type_call(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    PyObject *obj;
    PyThreadState *tstate = _PyThreadState_GET();

    if (type == &PyType_Type) {
        assert(args != NULL && PyTuple_Check(args));
        assert(kwds == NULL || PyDict_Check(kwds));
        Py_ssize_t nargs = PyTuple_GET_SIZE(args);

        if (nargs == 1 && (kwds == NULL || !PyDict_GET_SIZE(kwds))) {
            obj = (PyObject *) Py_TYPE(PyTuple_GET_ITEM(args, 0));
            return Py_NewRef(obj);
        }
        if (nargs != 3) {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,
                            "type() takes 1 or 3 arguments");
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    if (type->tp_new == NULL) {
        _PyErr_Format(tstate, PyExc_TypeError,
                      "cannot create '%s' instances", type->tp_name);
        return NULL;
    }

    obj = type->tp_new(type, args, kwds);
    obj = _Py_CheckFunctionResult(tstate, (PyObject*)type, obj, NULL);
    if (obj == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if (!PyObject_TypeCheck(obj, type))
        return obj;

    type = Py_TYPE(obj);
    if (type->tp_init != NULL) {
        int res = type->tp_init(obj, args, kwds);
        if (res < 0) {
            assert(_PyErr_Occurred(tstate));
            Py_SETREF(obj, NULL);
        }
        else {
            assert(!_PyErr_Occurred(tstate));
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Возможно здесь не всё понятно сразу, особенно если вы никогда не писали на чистом Си, но здесь представлен основной код реализации метода `__call__` у встроенного класса `type`. Именно он и вызывается, когда вы вызываете `t=Test()`
Например, вместо вызова как сверху, вы можете создать объект с аналогичным поведением вот так:

```py
t = type.__call__(Test)
```

При этом порядок вывода не изменится.

Как мы выяснили, вызов `__new__` происходит при вызове `__call__` у `type`, который неявно вызывается при создании объекта.

Внутри питона (то бишь в исходниках на Cи) выделяется память под новый объект, который мы получаем из функции `__new__`, которую мы переопределяем в нашем классе. После этого, на моменте `int res = type->tp_init(obj, args, kwds);`
вызывается функция `__init__`, которая инициализирует наш объект (устанавливает поля и т.д.)

И вот этот полученный объект нам и возвращается в переменную `t`, которую мы объявили в питоне.

Кстати, если посмотреть в исходники, можно заметить проверку:

```
if (!PyObject_TypeCheck(obj, type))
    return obj;
```

Эта проверка происходит **до** момента вызова `tp_init` (то бишь питоновской функции `__init__`)

Как не трудно догадаться, проверяет она соответствие полученного объекта классу, для которого мы его создавали. Что это значит? Что если из функции `__new__` мы вернем объект, не являющийся экземпляром нашего класса, то `__init__` вызываться не будет. Например:

```py
class Other:
    def __init__(self):
        print('other __init__ called')

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('other __new__ called')
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('other __call__ called')
        
class Test:
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'__call__ called with value {self.value}')

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('__new__ called')
        return Other()

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = '999'
        print('__init__ called')


t = Test()
```

Вывод будет:

```
__new__ called
other __new__ called
other __init__ called
```

Здесь при создании объекта вызвалась функция `__new__` из класса `Test`. В ней из нее мы вернули экземпляр класса `Other`. При его создании вызвалась `other __new__`. И после этого вызывалась `other __init__`. Основной `__init__` (из класса `Test`) Так и не вызвался. Заметьте, что `__init__` класса `Other` был вызван, потому что из функции `__new__` класса `Other` мы возвращаем `super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)`. То есть возвращаем то, что нам вернет функция `__new__`, определенная у родителя (родителем по умолчанию будет класс `object`). И именно `object.__new__` и вызывается, если ваш класс не переопределяет функцию `__new__`.

**Эксперимент:** Попробуйте в классе `Other` из `__new__` вернуть пустой объект `object()`. Тогда вы увидите, что `other __init__` тоже не будет вызван.

Кстати, никто не запрещает вызывать `__init__` напрямую из `__new__`, например вот так:

```py
class Other:
    def __init__(self):
        print('other __init__ called')

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('other __new__ called')
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('other __call__ called')

class Test:
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'__call__ called with value {self.value}')

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('__new__ called')
        obj = Other()
        cls.__init__(obj)
        return obj

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = '999'
        print('__init__ called')


t = Test()
#print('some string printed')
t()
```

Вывод:

```
__new__ called
other __new__ called
other __init__ called
__init__ called
other __call__ called
```

Как видно, здесь `Test.__init__` был вызван, но при попытке вызова `t()`, запускается функция из класса `Other`. Потому что именно объект класса Other мы вернули из `Test.__new__`.

```py
print(type(t)) # <class '__main__.Other'>
```

**Итак. Подведем итог:**

При создании экземпляра класса:

Вызывается `Test.__new__`. Которая возвращает объект.

После этого (если `__new__` вернула объект типа Test или его наследника) вызывается `Test.__init__`, устанавливающий все нужные поля и т.д.

**Когда стоит переопределять `__new__`, а когда `__init__`?**

Простой ответ:

в 99.9% случаев стоит переопределять `__init__`

Сложный ответ:

`__new__` стоит переопределять, когда при создании экземпляра класса может быть необходима какая-то логика связанная с тем, будет ли вообще по итогу создан новый объект, или нет. Например: Если при создании нового объекта нам нужно следить за количеством уже созданных экземпляров и т.п.

`__init__` же стоит переопределять тогда, когда при создании объекты мы хотим задать этому объекту какие-то поля, вызвать какие-то внешние функции (например напечатать что-то и т.п.), которые не затрагивают информацию о других созданных экземплярах класса и т.п. (**Практически всегда**)

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, как на самом деле, но могу предположить.

Мы знаем, что метод `__call__` класса управляет вызовами **экземпляра** этого класса, а не вызовами самого класса.

То есть метод `__call__` класса `A` срабатывает, когда мы делаем `A()()`. Значит, если мы хотим найти метод, который вызывается просто при `A()`, нам нужно пойти назад по цепочке и понять, экземпляром какого класса является сам класс `A`.

А так как все классы являются экземплярами класса `type`, то логично предположить, что при `A()` у нас вызывается как раз `type.__call__`